# How to select students that failed at least at all courses that student with id = 1 failed?

Tags: oracle, join, relational-division, minus

I have the following tables:

```
STUDENT (student_id, first_name, last_name, birth_date, year , domain)

PROFESSOR (professor_id, first_name, last_name, birth_date, hire_date, title, salary)

COURSE (course_id, course_name, professor_id)

GRADE (student_id, course_id, grade, date_of_exam)
```

I have to display the students that failed at least at all the courses that student with `id = 1` failed.

What I tried:

```
SELECT
s.student_id,
s.first_name,
s.last_name,
n.grade,
n.course_id
FROM
    student s
    JOIN grade n ON n.student_id = s.student_id
WHERE
    n.grade <= 4;
```

...this gets all the students that failed but I don't know how to go from this to all the students that failed at least at all the courses that student with `id  = 1` failed. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful!

**Additional details**

For example: If student with `id = 1` failed at courses with `ids = 2,3`. And we have other two students who failed at courses with `ids  = 2,3` (like student 1) and they might fail at other courses too, then I want to display those two students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of getting your desired results

```
SELECT *
FROM   STUDENT S
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT g1.course_id
                   FROM   GRADE g1
                   WHERE  g1.student_id = 1
                          AND g1.grade <= 4
                   MINUS
                   SELECT g2.course_id
                   FROM   GRADE g2
                   WHERE  g2.student_id = S.student_id
                          AND g2.grade <= 4)
```

For each student it checks with `MINUS` whether there are any courses that student_id = 1 has failed that are not in the set of failed courses for the student under focus.

If there are no such courses then the `NOT EXISTS` evaluates to true and the student is returned.

student_id = 1 will be returned as they have obviously failed at least as many courses as themselves so you may want to filter that out.

Answer (score 0):

This should lump all the students who failed the same class together:

```
    with failboat as (select s.student_ID, c.course_id, g.Grade, 
    rank() over (partition by s.student_id order by date_of_exam) as failcount
    from STUDENT s
    inner join GRADE  on s.student_ID = g.student_ID
    inner join Course c on g.course_ID = c.course_ID
    where g.grade <=4)

    select f1.*, f2.*
    from failboat f1
    inner join failboat f2 on f1.courseID = f2.CourseID
```